# Can't ping non-domain joined client by name from subnet but Name and IP appeared in addresslease on dns server

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dhcp, nslookup, ipconfig

is it posible to resolve the name of a non-domain joined device by ping? the dns server has registered the device. name and Ip are registered in addresslease.

Ok, this is what I have tried:

- If I ping the client-name in the same subnet it gives me a feedback but its end in a timeout.
- nslookup "computername" = "computername" not found: non-existent domain
- On DNS Server (different vlan) = Ping request could not find Host "computername". Please check the name and try again.
- I can ping this client in all vlans
- can't determine that issue on domain-joined devices

Okay, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out:

'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security' -> Inbound Rules -> 'File and Printer(Echo Request ICMPv4' right klick on properties -> Tab "Range' -> 'Remote-IP-Adresse'
Type in address range or direct ip address of remote computer(s)

I seen that tip by gb5102 on:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1984824-ping-replies-on-local-subnet-but-not-to-hosts-on-another-subnet